# Linux Shell Script to unzip and split file outputs unreadable files

Tags: linux, shell

I have a zip folder which contains multiple files of same format. Each file with around 50 mb size. I need to split each file into multiple chuncks (say 1000 lines per spllited output file).

I have written a shell script which which unzips the folder and saves the split files output in a directory.

The problem is that the output chunks are in unreadable format containing symbols and random characters. 
When I do it for each file individually, it outputs perfect txt split files. But it is not happening for whole zip folder.

Anyone knows how to can I get those files in txt format.
Here is my script.

```
for z in input.zip ; do
    if unzip -p "$z" | split -l 1000 $z output_dir ; then
    echo "$z"
fi
done
```

Comment: What are the contents of your zip file? Do you get any plain text (or whatever) output in the split files?

Comment: This is going to stream the *entire* contents of *every* file in `input.zip` to the pipe and then split will operate on the *total contents*. Is that what you want?

Comment: The value for `$z` will be `input.zip`, and this loop will run 1 time. Is that what you want? Also, you'll need to tell `split` to read from std-in with just a plain `-` instead of `$z`. you version of the `split` man page may mention this (mine does). AND I don't think you can specify an output_dir as  you have done here. Just make it work in the current dir before  you start adding features ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You need to unzip the files first. Otherwise, you are just chunking the original binary ZIP file.

### Solution

The following is untested because I don't have your source file. However, it should work for you with a little tweaking.

```
unzip -d /tmp/unzipped input.zip
mkdir /tmp/split_files

for file in /tmp/unzipped/*txt do;
    split -l 1000 "$file" "/tmp/split_files/$(basename "$file" .txt)"
done
```